# Meaning of zero Lagrangian and connection to Poynting theorem

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, action, poynting-vector

I have an electromagnetic field system for a cavity with a current source, whose Lagrangian has the form

$$ L=\int_V dV (w_{e}+w_{h} +i(E\cdot J)/\omega)+ \oint_A dA (E\times H)\cdot \hat{n},  $$

where $w_e$, $w_h$ are the electric/magnetic energy densities, $E,H$ are the fields, $J$ is a current density, $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $\hat{n}$ is the surface normal vector pointing out of the cavity surface, $A$ is area and $V$ is volume.

This lagrangian representation is correct because from it we can derive other known equations about this system, including Maxwell's equations.

However, one can also regonize the right hand side of this equation as a statement of Poynting's theorem (in integral form), which must give zero ($L=0$ here) to guarantee power balance in the system.

This is a bit confusing to me, because the Lagrangian now is zero. I would like to understand what does that mean? And how can we work with such situation in practice so that we may continue with variational caluclations using $L$ if we want to (e.g. finding field eigen solutions, etc, by extermizing the action).

I thought about the fact that $L$ is not unique and we can write the same dynamics by adding a constant energy to $L$, or by adding to $L$ a total derivative in time or position of any arbitrary function $f(E,H)$ (e.g. $L\rightarrow L+df/dt$), without affecting the system. But I am not sure if this helps and, if it does, how to choose/adjust such additions.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that the action/Lagrangian is an off-shell$^1$ expression, while the [Poynting's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem) only holds on-shell$^1$. If one applies the EOMs in the action, one invalidates the [principle of stationary action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_action).

--

$^1$The words *on-shell* and *off-shell* refer to whether the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations (=EOM) are satisfied or not.

Comment: I guess your referral to the mass shell is from quantum field theory context, rather than classical; am I correct?  I didn't know about the shell concept, but I tried to read about it a bit. Is there a way to explain this purely classically, since this is a classical problem? So far I agree that applying Euler-Lagrange equation (which leads to Poynting's theorem also here) to our L will make it =0. But I don't see why does this "invalidate" the least action principle, as the Euler-Lagrange equation itself stems from that principle, and it seems to me that being on-shell is just a special case.

Comment: If you could expand your answer a bit more to explain the meaning of this, preferably in classical terms, it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The answer only uses classical (=non-quantum) physics.